# Request Denied After Getting Admin Consent on Tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I went through the process to get admin consent for a POC app (delegated) I am building that leverages the new Presence API via MS Graph

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

However, when I try to make a Graph API Call, I am able to get a token, but get this error when I try to hit the /me endpoint (gets my AD Info)

```
Failed to call the Web Api: Forbidden
Content: {
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
    "request-id": "0c293c6f-f8d2-4a12-8879-c52b16e4c51f",
    "date": "2020-01-07T18:09:14"
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure what this error is from, anyone here that can help me? My app has permissions for

- User.Read
- User.Read.All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this issue is to update the authentication flow to use the 'On behalf of a user flow'. This will give you a delegated access token and the context of a user to return their presence information. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

Answer (score 0):

> admin consent for a POC app

Sounds like you're using the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service).  If that's the case then the presence-get doc you linked shows that this call is not supported for admin consent.

---

[image]

---

That doesn't necessarily mean it won't work but...

...if you want to keep trying add the **Presence.Read** and **Presence.Read.All** permission to your app and see if that helps.